# OpenLayers : Draw shape from external geojson file

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I am trying to draw a shape (airplane) from external geojson file. Said shape uses data from 2 object structures inside the geojson file. I can load both shapes separately, but I can't append/join them together.

Answer (score 2):

You have to merge your polygons before displaying them. The accepted answer in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19964/how-to-merge-two-polygons-in-openlayers) question explains how to achieve that in detail.

Comment: that's an OL2 solution not an OL3, Is it working for OL3 too ?

Answer (score 2):

for OL3 it's a bit complicated since you'll have to read both features from both sources and do an union to them then you load them to a vector layer,

the union itself is made with turf you can download it from [here](http://turfjs.org/):

```
 var feature1,feature2;
 var union=turf.union(feature1,feature2);

 var formatGeoJSON= new ol.format.GeoJSON();
 var yourResult=formatGeoJSON.readFeature(union);
```

Now you can load it in a vector layer to your map